# How do I read out my data set with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have tried to write a Python script to do filter out some information from the following dataset:

```
>Feature NC_000913<
190 255 CDS
            gene    thrL
            inference   NCBI RefSeq Database
            inference   UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot:P0AD86
            locus_tag   16127995
            product thr operon leader peptide
337 2799    CDS
            gene    thrA
            inference   NCBI RefSeq Database
            inference   UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot:P00561
            locus_tag   16127996
            product Bifunctional aspartokinase/homoserine dehydrogenase 1
2801    3733    CDS
            gene    thrB
            inference   NCBI RefSeq Database
            inference   UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot:P00547
            locus_tag   16127997
            product homoserine kinase
3734    5020    CDS
            gene    thrC
            inference   NCBI RefSeq Database
            inference   UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot:P00934
            locus_tag   16127998
            product L-threonine synthase
5234    5530    CDS
            gene    yaaX
            inference   NCBI RefSeq Database
            inference   UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot:P75616
            locus_tag   16127999
            product DUF2502 family putative periplasmic protein
```

I need the task to search for gaps that are over 20 numbers long, ex. 255 - 337. It should then write in a text file the gap and the Swiss-Prot id ex. P0AD86 - P00561.
I tried to use pandas as I thought it would suit this task. 
My try was:

```
import pandas as sd

df = pd.read_csv("K12.tbl", error_bad_lines=False, header=(0), engine='python')

print(df.head(21))
```

Trying to get a sorting from my .tbl file into a structured table, this is my output:

```
>Feature NC_000913<
0                                       190\t255\tCDS
1                                    \t\t\tgene\tthrL
2               \t\t\tinference\tNCBI RefSeq Database
3        \t\t\tinference\tUniProtKB/Swiss-Prot:P0AD86
4                           \t\t\tlocus_tag\t16127995
5            \t\t\tproduct\tthr operon leader peptide
6                                      337\t2799\tCDS
7                                    \t\t\tgene\tthrA
8               \t\t\tinference\tNCBI RefSeq Database
9        \t\t\tinference\tUniProtKB/Swiss-Prot:P00561
10                          \t\t\tlocus_tag\t16127996
11  \t\t\tproduct\tBifunctional aspartokinase/homo...
12                                    2801\t3733\tCDS
13                                   \t\t\tgene\tthrB
14              \t\t\tinference\tNCBI RefSeq Database
15       \t\t\tinference\tUniProtKB/Swiss-Prot:P00547
16                          \t\t\tlocus_tag\t16127997
17                   \t\t\tproduct\thomoserine kinase
18                                    3734\t5020\tCDS
19                                   \t\t\tgene\tthrC
20              \t\t\tinference\tNCBI RefSeq Database
Skipping line 37: Expected 1 fields in line 37, saw 2
Skipping line 79: Expected 1 fields in line 79, saw 2
Skipping line 85: Expected 1 fields in line 85, saw 2
```

(https://pastebin.com/N1z9mpqb). 
I dont know how to get a proper table and how to compare those numbers to find the gaps. Its my first time doing a dataanalysis...
I hope  that someone will be able to help me out and thanks for any ideas :D

Comment: Looks like your data is tab delimited. Could `df = pd.read_csv("K12.tbl", sep='\t', ...)` give better results?

Comment: I tried, https://pastebin.com/207ij78c. This was my result:  https://pastebin.com/F3j1RtQn. So it skips the:             `gene    thrL
            inference   NCBI RefSeq Database
            inference   UniProtKB/Swiss-Prot:P0AD86
            locus_tag   16127995
            product thr operon leader peptide`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import pandas as pd
with open('K12.tbl', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

# Get rid of newlines
data = [x.replace('\n','') for x in data]
# Get rid of row number and leading spaces
data = [re.sub('(\d+\s{2,})','',x) for x in data]
# Get rid of leading tabs
data = [re.sub('(\\\\t){3}','',x) for x in data]
# Get rid of footer lines
data = [x for x in data[1:] if 'Skipping' not in x]

# Get every 6th element which contains the number ranges you want
numbers = data[::6]
# Split the numbers into columns
numbers = [x.split('\\t') for x in numbers]

# Create a dataframe of the start/stop/cds values
df = pd.DataFrame(numbers, columns=['start','stop','cds'])

# Shift the start column back one row to create column that holds the next start number
df['next_start'] = df['start'].shift(-1)

# Fill the last next_start NAN with zero
df = df.fillna(0)

# Create binary map of which rows represent larger than allowed skips
big_diff = df['next_start'].astype(int) - df['stop'].astype(int) > 20

# Get list of indexes where the skips are too big
big_diff_index = big_diff[big_diff].index.values

# The value you want is in the 3rd row after each set of numbers, get that row and split on :, return the value at the end
[data[x+3].split(':')[-1] for x in big_diff_index]
```

Output

```
['P0AD86']
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately I get the following error message: https://pastebin.com/jCT76sDH

Comment: try print(numbers) and see what's in there

Comment: I gives me this: [['190\t255\tCDS'], ['337\t2799\tCDS'], ['2801\t3733\tCDS'], ['3734\t5020\tCDS'], ['5234\t5530\tCDS'], ['6459\t5683\tCDS'], ['7959\t6529\tCDS'], ['8238\t9191\tCDS'], ['9306\t9893\tCDS'], ['10494\t9928\tCDS'], ['11356\t10643\tCDS'], ['11786\t11382\tCDS'], ['12163\t14079\tCDS'], ['14168\t15298\tCDS'], ['15445\t16557\tCDS'], ['16960\t16751\tCDS'], ['16903\t16751\tCDS'], ['17489\t18655\tCDS'], ['18715\t19620\tCDS'], ['20314\t19811\tCDS'], ['20508\t20233\tCDS'], ['21078\t20815\tCDS']...

Comment: try changing numbers = [x.split('\\t') for x in numbers] to numbers = [x[0].split('\t') for x in numbers]

Comment: I changed numbers=... and got this error message: https://pastebin.com/cFrJf2DH with this results from print(numbers): https://pastebin.com/yt7nSMNX     Maybe something in the 21. line? :`20# Create a dataframe of the start/stop/cds values
---> 21 df = pd.DataFrame(numbers, columns=['start','stop','cds'])
     22 
     23 # Shift the start column back one row to create column that holds the next start number`

Answer (score 0):

Your file is tab delimited, but the header line gives no indication on the number of fields. You can use the `names` parameter as a hint:

```
df = pd.read_csv("K12.tbl", sep='\t', names=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], error_bad_lines=False)
```